# In Gmail, using Google Apps Script, is it possible to forward the TRANSLATED emails which I receive to another email address?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, web-applications, localization, gmail

I receive many emails in Japanese everyday (I am living in Japan). Gmail automatically detect that the email is written in Japanese, so that one can click the "translate" button and get it translated. I would like to forward the translated email to another email address (or to a mailing list). It is easy to set up the mail forwarding, but when I do, only the original message (in Japanese) is forwarded. So my question is:

Is it possible, using Google Apps Scripts script (or any another tool), to forward the TRANSLATED emails which I receive to another email address?

I am a very beginner with Google tools, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in LanguageApp service to translate text.

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads().forEach((thread) => {
  thread
    .getMessages()
    .filter((message) => {
      return (
        message.getFrom().toLowerCase().indexOf("sender@example.com") !== -1
      );
    })
    .forEach((message) => {
      if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 1) {
        message.forward("email@example.com", {
          htmlBody: LanguageApp.translate(message.getBody(), "jp", "en"),
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: if I want to trigger this filter only for a specific email address, may I write something like        
 GmailApp.getInboxThreads().forEach(function(thread) {
    thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message) { 
if (message.SENDER ="email2@example.com" {
      message.forward("email@example.com", {
         htmlBody: LanguageApp.translate(message.getBody(), "jp", "en")
      }
    }
})
  }

what should I use instead of SENDER?

Comment: @sintetico - updated the code to include additional checks, including quota.

Comment: may I ask what is the quota check doing?

Comment: I created the script

function myFunction() {
GmailApp.getInboxThreads().forEach((thread) => {
  thread.getMessages().filter((message) => {
      return (
        message.getFrom().toLowerCase().indexOf("xxxx@icloud.com") !== -1
      );
    }).forEach((message) => {
      if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 1) {
        message.forward("yyyy@icloud.com", {
          htmlBody: LanguageApp.translate(message.getBody(), "ja", "en"),
        });
      }
    });
});
}

...

Comment: ...
and I run it, but nothing happens. The script runs for ~30 seconds, but no mail is forwarded. (I changed jp into ja because https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages)

Answer (score 2):

To complete [@Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512127/amit-agarwal)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714238/7453656):

You can build your filter based on the sender using the `.getFrom()` method on a message instance. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getfrom) you can find an example.

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads().forEach( thread => { 
    thread.getMessages().forEach( message => {
         if (message.getFrom() === "email2@example.com" { 
              message.forward("email@example.com", { htmlBody: LanguageApp.translate(message.getBody(), "jp", "en") }
         }
    });
});
```

### Reference

[GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)